# Minecraft How are Chunk Sections stored

Tags: minecraft, chunks

I am currently making a Minecraft chunk manipulation program, and I would like to know how Minecraft chunk sections are stored.

From the [Minecraft Wiki Article on how Minecraft Stores its chunks](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Chunk_format).

> Sections: List of Compound tags, each tag is a sub-chunk of sorts.
>
> An individual Section.
>
> Y: The Y index (not coordinate) of this section. Range 0 to 15 (bottom to top), with no duplicates but some sections may be missing if empty.
>
> Blocks: 4096 bytes of block IDs defining the terrain. 8 bits per block, plus ? the bits from the below Add tag.
>
> Add: May not exist. 2048 bytes of additional block ID data. The value to add to (combine with) the above block ID to form the true block ID in the range 0 to 4095. 4 bits per block. Combining is done by shifting this value to the left 8 bits and then adding it to the block ID from above.
>
> Data: 2048 bytes of block data additionally defining parts of the terrain. 4 bits per block.
>
> BlockLight: 2048 bytes recording the amount of block-emitted light in each block. Makes load times faster compared to recomputing at load time. 4 bits per block.
>
> SkyLight: 2048 bytes recording the amount of sunlight or moonlight hitting         each block. 4 bits per block.

But I do not understand how `Blocks` is read. Every Section in a Chunk is 16 x 16 x 16 blocks. But instead Minecraft stores the blocks in a section in a **1-d** array.

Answer (score 5):

A 3D array is also stored linear in RAM. You need to convert coordinates to an index. For the "Blocks" Tag its this formula:

```
Index = Ycoord * 256 + Zcoord * 16 + Xcoord
```

This is called YZX-order. The tags "HeightMap" or "Biomes" use ZX-order (Index = Zcoord * 16 + X)

Comment: Why do people call it 'YZX-order', which puts the major-order (X) last?
As that stands, 'ZX-order' would be a subset of 'YZX-order' ... 
Wouldn't it make more sense to call these 'XZY' and 'XZ' ordering?  This way we could say "XZ-ordering is a subset of XZY-ordering". This would put the LSB first in the name, just like 'row-major' and 'col-major' already do.