# Why does storing coordinates as YZX take up less space than storing them as XZY?

Tags: java, 3d, binary, compression, minecraft

In recent Minecraft patch-notes some changes were made to the way it saves world data.

[said change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dR6nL.png)

[link to wiki page](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Anvil_file_format)

This included a change from storing coordinates (presumably of entities) in the format of **XZY** to **YZX**.

Minecraft's Y coordinate is height, which used to range from 0 to 256, but with the same update that brought this optimisation it was changed to the range of -64 to 256.

I imagine that the reason that this is faster is something to do with the two's compliment representation of Y needing a sign bit at the front, but I can't visualise any reason why this would be faster.

An explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not ask the authors?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but I think that it comes form chunks system and how sections are stored, I have been looking for reasons and the answer could be here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32671125/14712559

Here it is explained how it works, biomes use ZX-order and using YZX-order could be faster to render the graphics. Perhaps you are aware of this info, take a look to this question and tell me :D.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it seems to make more sense that the coordinates are used to generate a key/index for the list of blocks. Looking at the equation to generate the indexes (from the wiki), it looks as though the x,y,z coordinates are stored as different powers of 16. Although all 3 values will range from 0-15, i guess using the y coordinate as the highest power is more optimal since you can be pretty confident that there won't be as many gaps on the y-axis. I'm extrapolating, but i'll update this thread if find a proper solution.